# Is there any tool create php proxy class for web service (wsdl)?

Tags: php, wsdl

Hi
 Is there any tool for generating php proxy classes for webservice for php programming language?
 Web services are developed in .net.
 
nRk

Comment: Proxy or Mock? Please provide more details about what you want to use the class for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

[Zend_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html)

> The Zend_Soap_Client class simplifies
>   SOAP client development for PHP
>   programmers.
>
> It may be used in WSDL or non-WSDL
>   mode.
>
> Under the WSDL mode, the
>   Zend_Soap_Client component uses a WSDL
>   document to define transport layer
>   options.

Example code:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("MyService.wsdl");
$result1 = $client->method1(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in PHP SoapClient class:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");

// To call an Add method on the .NET-based service, that takes 2 parameters:
$arguments->a = 1;
$arguments->b = 2;

$result = $client->Add( $arguments );

echo( "1 + 2 = " . $result->AddResult );
```